# How do you send slices of a Vec to a task in rust?

Tags: rust

So, this doesn't work:

```
use std::comm;

#[deriving(Show)]
struct St { v: u8 }

fn main() {

  let mut foo:Vec<St> = Vec::new();
  for i in range(0u8, 10) {
    foo.push(St { v: i });
  }

  {
      let mut foo_slice = foo.as_mut_slice();
      let (f1, f2) = foo_slice.split_at_mut(5);

      let (sl, rx):(Sender<Option<&mut [St]>>, Receiver<Option<&mut [St]>>) = comm::channel();
      let (sx, rl):(Sender<bool>, Receiver<bool>) = comm::channel();

      spawn(proc() {
        loop {
          let v = rx.recv();
          match v {
            Some(v) => {
                v[0].v = 100u8;
                sx.send(true);
            },
            None => {
                sx.send(false);
                break;
            }
          }
        }
      });

      sl.send(Some(f1));
      sl.send(Some(f2));
      sl.send(None);

      println!("{}", rl.recv());
      println!("{}", rl.recv());
      println!("{}", rl.recv());
  }

  println!("{}", foo);
}
```

...because:

```
sl.send(Some(f1));
sl.send(Some(f2));
sl.send(None);
```

Infers that the variables f1 and f2 must be 'static, because the task may outlive the function it is running in. Which in turn means that foo must be 'static, and not 'a, which is the lifetime of main().

Thus the somewhat odd error:

```
<anon>:14:27: 14:30 error: `foo` does not live long enough
<anon>:14       let mut foo_slice = foo.as_mut_slice();
                                    ^~~
note: reference must be valid for the static lifetime...
<anon>:6:11: 46:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 6:10
<anon>:6 fn main() {
<anon>:7  
<anon>:8   let mut foo:Vec<St> = Vec::new();
<anon>:9   for i in range(0u8, 10) {
<anon>:10     foo.push(St { v: i });
<anon>:11   }
```

So, to fix this I thought that using Box <Vec<Foo>> might be the solution, but even then the slices created will have a local lifetime.

I could use unsafe code to transmute the lifetime (this does actually work), but is there a way to safely do the same thing?

playpen: http://is.gd/WQBdSB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rust prevents you from having mutable access to the same value from within multiple tasks, because that leads to data races. Specifically, a task can't have borrowed pointers (incl. slices) to a value that is owned by another task.

To allow multiple tasks to access the same object, you should use [`Arc<T>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html). To provide mutable access to the object, put a [`RefCell<T>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) in that `Arc`: `Arc<RefCell<T>>`. As for that `T`, you can't use a slice type, as I just explained. I suggest you create 2 different `Arc<RefCell<Vec<St>>>` objects, send a clone of an `Arc<RefCell<Vec<St>>>` on the channel and join the `Vec`s when the tasks have done their job.

In general, when doing parallel algorithms, you should avoid mutating shared state. This leads to poor performance, because the system needs to invalidate memory caches across cores. If possible, consider having the task allocate and hold on to its result until it's complete, and send the complete result over a channel, rather than a mere `bool`.

**EDIT**

We can reformulate your initial program in terms of ownership to understand why it's not sound. The stack frame for the call to `main` owns `foo`, the `Vec`. `foo_slice`, `f1` and `f2` borrow that `Vec`. You spawn a task. **That task may outlive the call frame for `main`**, and even outlive the task that spawned it. Therefore, it is illegal to send references to values that are constrained to a stack frame. This is why borrowed pointers, with the exception of `&'static T`, don't fulfill [`Send`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/kinds/trait.Send.html).

Boxing the `Vec` changes nothing, because the stack frame still owns the `Box`, so returning from the function will drop the box and its contents.

The compiler cannot verify that the task won't outlive the owner of the values you send references to to the task. If you are **sure** that the task will terminate before the references you give it become invalid, you can use [`transmute`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/intrinsics/ffi.transmute.html) to cheat on the lifetime, but this is unsafe.

Comment: Nonsense. That may be true in general, but specifically in this case if I partition a massive linear array into non over lapping parts (specifically what split_at_mut does), its not possible to have memory race conditions or UB. The memory is treated as two independent segments. There's no reason at all to use Arc for this. I *can* do it using unsafe pointers and transmute(), I'm looking for a safe way to do the equivalent.

Comment: @Doug, it is still not safe, since the task that owns the vector may disappear (and deallocate the vector) before the subtasks are done. It is more than just data races that apply here.

Comment: @dbaupp mmm... so you're saying that the main thread can terminate before any of it's child tasks? I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: @Doug: Yes. There's no relationship among the lifetime of tasks. See my edit.