# Lifetime problems passing &mut to function and returning a closure

Tags: closures, rust, mutable, lifetime

I have a short example of incrementing a vector by divide and conquer. Very basic, I just can't get the lifetimes correct. I'm pretty sure it has to do with `&'s mut` argument lifetime and the `TaskResult<'s>` return lifetime, but I'm not sure how to make it work.

The [code on the playpen](http://is.gd/ZaQUbH)

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    let t = inc_vec(data.as_mut_slice());
}

pub type MyClosure<'s> = FnMut() -> TaskResult<'s> + Send + 's;

pub enum TaskResult<'s> {
    Done(usize),
    Fork(Vec<Box<MyClosure<'s>>>),
}

fn inc_vec<'s>(data: &'s mut [usize]) -> TaskResult {
    if data.len() <= 4 {
        inc_vec_direct(data)
    } else {
        inc_vec_fork(data)
    }
}

fn inc_vec_fork<'s>(data: &'s mut [usize]) -> TaskResult<'s> {
    let mid = data.len()/2;
    let (l,r) = data.split_at_mut(mid);

    let task_l: Box<MyClosure<'s>> = Box::new(move || {
        inc_vec(l)
    });
    let task_r: Box<MyClosure<'s>> = Box::new(move || {
        inc_vec(r)
    });

    TaskResult::Fork(vec![task_l, task_r])
}

fn inc_vec_direct(data: &mut [usize]) -> TaskResult {
    for d in data {
        *d += 1;
    }
    TaskResult::Done(1)
}
```

And it gives me the following error (truncated since the same error is produced twice, once for `task_l` and once for `task_r`):

```
src/main.rs:26:17: 26:18 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for automatic coercion due to conflicting requirements
src/main.rs:26         inc_vec(l)
                               ^
src/main.rs:25:55: 27:6 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime  as defined on the block at 25:54...
src/main.rs:25     let task_l: Box<MyClosure<'s>> = Box::new(move || {
src/main.rs:26         inc_vec(l)
src/main.rs:27     });
src/main.rs:26:17: 26:18 note: ...so that closure can access `l`
src/main.rs:26         inc_vec(l)
                               ^
src/main.rs:21:62: 33:2 note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime 's as defined on the block at 21:61...
src/main.rs:21 fn inc_vec_fork<'s>(data: &'s mut [usize]) -> TaskResult<'s> {
src/main.rs:22     let mid = data.len()/2;
src/main.rs:23     let (l,r) = data.split_at_mut(mid);
src/main.rs:24
src/main.rs:25     let task_l: Box<MyClosure<'s>> = Box::new(move || {
src/main.rs:26         inc_vec(l)
               ...
src/main.rs:25:38: 27:7 note: ...so that trait type parameters matches those specified on the impl (expected `TaskResult<'_>`, found `TaskResult<'s>`)
src/main.rs:25     let task_l: Box<MyClosure<'s>> = Box::new(move || {
src/main.rs:26         inc_vec(l)
src/main.rs:27     });
```

There must be a simple fix to this. All I want to say is that I return a vector of closures that have mutable references to parts of the input slice. I guess I have to mark the closure lifetime as shorter than the data slice lifetime, just not sure how to do that.

Comment: There's no simple fix to this because it is inherently unsafe to pass references to threads, since the parent thread who owns the reference can terminate before the other threads, invalidating what the references in the children point to. You'll have to change your design a little bit. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477757/how-do-you-send-slices-of-a-vec-to-a-task-in-rust for possible workarounds.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves this is not entirely correct because there is a machinery which makes sure that a reference won't outlive the parent stack frame (see [`thread::scoped`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scoped.html)) even if it passed to another thread. In this particular case there are even no threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your example to compile and run if you change one line:

```rust
pub type MyClosure<'s> = FnOnce() -> TaskResult<'s> + Send + 's;
//                       ^~~~~~
```

I'm still thinking through how to explain it though!

This is the code I was starting from. I made a few simplifications to get started, mostly around removing the lifetime references where they aren't needed. Lifetime elision means that `fn(foo: &T) -> &U` is the same as `fn<'a>(foo: &'a T) -> &'a U`, but **not the same** as `fn<'a>(foo: &'a T) -> &U`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    let t = inc_vec(data.as_mut_slice());
}

pub type MyClosure<'s> = FnMut() -> TaskResult<'s> + Send + 's;

pub enum TaskResult<'s> {
    Done(usize),
    Fork(Vec<Box<MyClosure<'s>>>),
}

fn inc_vec(data: &mut [usize]) -> TaskResult {
    if data.len() <= 4 {
        inc_vec_direct(data)
    } else {
        inc_vec_fork(data)
    }
}

fn inc_vec_fork(data: &mut [usize]) -> TaskResult {
    let mid = data.len() / 2;
    let (l, r) = data.split_at_mut(mid);

    let task_l: Box<MyClosure> = Box::new(move || inc_vec(l));
    let task_r: Box<MyClosure> = Box::new(move || inc_vec(r));

    TaskResult::Fork(vec![task_l, task_r])
}

fn inc_vec_direct(data: &mut [usize]) -> TaskResult {
    for d in data { *d += 1; }
    TaskResult::Done(1)
}
```

Mostly, I got to the result by changing the closure just a smidge:

```rust
let task_l: Box<MyClosure> = Box::new(move || { let a = l; inc_vec(a)});
```

Which should be the same code. However, this has the error:

```
error: cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure
     let task_l: Box<MyClosure> = Box::new(move || { let a = l; inc_vec(a)});
                                                             ^
note: attempting to move value to here
     let task_l: Box<MyClosure> = Box::new(move || { let a = l; inc_vec(a)});
                                                         ^
help: to prevent the move, use `ref a` or `ref mut a` to capture value by reference
```

Which led me to try the various `Fn*` traits, with `FnOnce` working. I **think** that the solution boils down to the fact that Rust disallows aliasing of mutable references (a.k.a. you can't point to the same mutable thing twice). If you had a `FnMut` or `Fn`, then you could call the closure multiple times, which would give an opportunity to create aliases. It'd be awful nice if the error message included anything about mutability though!

A `FnOnce` is guaranteed to only be called once, which prevents that particular aliasing opportunity.

I think you could file 1 or 2 bugs from this:

1. It's surprising that the error message changes based on if there is a `let` or not.
2. It would be nice to mention mutability as the reason that the variable can't be moved into the closure.

Comment: You can't use the value of type `&mut [usize]` by borrowing inside the closure. You can only use it by moving it. Moving it requires `FnOnce`.

Comment: [A comment on your edit to the question as well as this answer.] Please use `<!-- language: lang-rust -->` on Rust code, it makes ugly `//'` formatting hacks at the end of a line unnecessary.

Comment: @Shepmaster: yeah, it’s still not as good as actually dealing with lifetime tokens properly, but the fact that it doesn’t highlighting it beyond line breaks is an improvement.

Comment: @Shepmaster: under Firefox for Android I experience no syntax highlighting.